# Sprite Kit SKLabel is not appearing when I initialize it in initWithSize:(CGSize)size

Tags: objective-c

I read up on other posts and changed view controller viewdidload to:

```
(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}
```

and I'm really not sure what the problem is. here is my code:

```
(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

      world=SKNode.node;
      [self addChild:world];

      self.anchorPoint= CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
      SKSpriteNode *ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] size: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 150)];
      ground.position= CGPointMake(0, -self.frame.size.height/2+ ground.frame.size.width/2);
      ground.physicsBody= [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ground.size];
      ground.physicsBody.dynamic=NO;

      NSLog(@"ground position: %f" ,  -self.frame.size.height/2+ ground.frame.size.width/2);

      [world addChild:ground];

      generator = [WorldGenerator generatorWithWorld:world];

      [self addChild:generator];
      [generator populate];

      hero = [MLHero hero];
      [world addChild:hero];
      pointsLabel =[SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ChalkDuster"];
      if (pointsLabel)
        NSLog(@"true");
      pointsLabel.fontColor=[SKColor redColor];
      pointsLabel.fontSize=40;
      pointsLabel.text=@"0";
      pointsLabel.position= CGPointMake(200,200); //I have tried many different values and none seem to work, including setting to the width and height etc.

      [self addChild:pointsLabel];
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Check the zPosition of the label. Put some high value like 100. Also, are you sure you want to add a label to the scene, and not to the world node? Next thing you can try, is to move this code to the didMoveToView, just to see if same thing happen. At the end, try to print out scene's size, view's size to see if everything is correct there...

Comment: thanks but its still not working when i use didmovetoview and zposition. As a beginner, i am quite confused to the difference between adding it to the scene and the world node. I want it to always be on the screen since its displaying points so isn't it logical to put it in the scene? thanks!

Comment: ok this is very strange for me but when i set   the position to:       pointsLabel.position= CGPointMake(hero.position.x, hero.position.y+50); it works. Can i please have an explanation? Thanks.

Comment: You can add nodes where ever you need. That's up to you. I just thought that maybe the main content is inside world node so you want your label there. There is noting wrong with adding a nodes to the scene :) You can try to check scene's size and view'size because maybe your scene's size differs from view's size and label is offscreen currently.